# SSIS : Set a flag in source table when record is Moved in target table(source and destination are different server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I would like to set a flag in source table, when a record is moved to destination table.

Example:
Source table:

| Id | Name | company | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ac | N |
| 2 | Sam | ac | N |

Once the destination table has data

| ID | name | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | ac |

Source table :

| Id | Name | company | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ac | Y |

Basically, I want to check if ID has been Generate  in target table, If it is genereat then make flag ' Y ' in source table.

How can I do this?

How can I create ssis task ?

Comment: The source table does not seem to have a `Primary Key` as a unique row identifier?

Comment: Primary have id column in source table.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to edit the question to show how the tables would really look like. Assuming they'd have real primary-key, and also foreign-key columns. So that readers could write a real answer :)

Comment: Consider a trigger on the destination on insert to update the source. Also, is ID in destination an identity or is it a match to source?

Comment: Those are different server